# Summarize table in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in using MVC and I have a question about summarizing the row data in a table.

Some background:

First I collect a lot of data with an ordinary SQL statement. I use a DataTable to store the data. Then I output the data with an ordinary HTML table. This works very nicely and I have no problems with it.

I would now like to summarize all of the values for each row and display the result in the bottom row.

*I know that I could do this already in the data layer. Loop through the datatable and summarize the values for the rows into a new row. Then finally append the "summary row" as the last row.*

Some code:

```
    <tr class="header">
      <th>Person</th>
      <th>NrOfRows</th>
    </tr>
    <% foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%: row["Name"].ToString()%></td>
        <td><%: row["NrOfRows"].ToString()%></td>
    </tr>
```

Could you please advice me which would be the best/easiest way to do this

Comment: I think the preferred way is to put the code into the controller or model code, not the view.

Comment: I totally agree and I have the code in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the calculation in the ControllerAction. something like this...

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var rows = this.repository.GetAll();
    this.ViewData["total"] = rows.AsEnumerable().Select(o => o["NrOfRows"]).Select(o => int.Parse(o)).Sum();  

    return this.View(rows);
}
```

Comment: I got the same problem here: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type ( I have stated: using System.Linq; )

Comment: It was the AsEnumerable() which was missing. The solution worked nicely. Thanks!

Comment: In my case I had to use Convert.ToInt32(o) instead of int.Parse(o)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider if you don't want to "pack" your data into a model (class). in mvc project in model section add class:

```
public class YourModel
{
 public string Name
 public int NrOfRows
 public YourModel(string name, int nrOfRows) 
 {
  Name = name;
  NrOfRows = nrOfRows;
 }
}
```

then in your controller method you do:

```
public ActionResult Summarize(/*parameters list*/) 
{
 var rows = (get data) //In here you assign here your table content
 ViewData.Model = rows.Select(row => new YourModel(row["Name"], int.Parse(row["NrOfRows"])));
 ViewData["nrRowCount"] = rows.Select(row => row.NrOfRows).Sum();
 return View();
}
```

and you go to the view:

```
<table>
<th>Person</th>
<th>nrOfRows</th>
 <%: foreach(var yourModel in Model) { :%>
   <tr>
     <td>yourModel.Name</td>
     <td>yourModel.NrOfRows</td>
   </tr>
  <%: } :%>
   <tr>
     <td>Summary: </td>
     <td> <%: ViewData["nrRowCount"] %:></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the following error when trying this code: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type  ( I have stated: using System.Linq; )

Comment: do you use "System.Data.DataSetExtensions" ? make sure you have using statements for System.Data and System.Linq. and you have to get your rows "AsEnumerable". more information in this topic: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/ad34a9f1-2849-478d-9405-b07a54b09aaf/ 

check out Steven Killick post!

Comment: Thanks it was the AsEnumerable() which was missing.

Comment: Thanks trn for the help. I gave you a vote up for the nice explanation.